# How to change application after deployed into Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I created one application in `Eclipse`. I deployed that application in `Google App Engine`. It deployed successfully. But now I want to do some changes in my application. Is it possible to add the changes? And also one more doubt: Is it possible to delete my application after the `deployment`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need re-deploy the whole application again.

You cannot selectively update parts of it.

What you can do, however, is deploy many versions at the same time, for example to test the most recent changes before rolling it out to the public. Every version is accessible via a different URL (*versionName.latest.appName.appspot.com*), and you can choose one of them to be the default one (*appName.appspot.com*). 
Keep in mind, though, that all versions use the same data store and memcache.

So, do not delete you local copy of the application (and more importantly its source, if this is a Java app) after deployment.

You can delete the application from App Engine (from Google's servers) using the Admin Console.

Answer (score 0):

If its a python app use the appcfg.py like this

```
appcfg.py --email=youremail@email.com update .
```

from the local directory of your application after making the updates.

Follow these links for more info.
Python: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html
Java: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html