# Is redeployment possible?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I created one web application in eclipse and successfully deployed it on google app engine. Then i do some modification in my program. How to do changes in the deployed application. Is their any option for redeployment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243368/how-to-change-application-after-deployed-into-google-app-engine
?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the google app engine plugin just click on the deploy button and it will re-deploy the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the version number in [appengine-web.xml](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#About_appengine_web_xml).
2. [Re-deploy](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html) using the Google App Engine [Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing.html).
3. Go to the [Admin console](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/theadminconsole.html) and set the new version as the default.

Voilà! You have just updated your app!